# Termination of PHP script between two mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible that a php script gets terminated between two mysql queries.

For example user registration:

1st INSERT : I will enter the basic first-name,last-name,address in one table

and

2nd INSERT :  i will enter the user's hashed password and salt in another table

This operation probably requires two queries and either of them independently are useless records.

What if the php script terminates after executing the first query?
User will just get a server error message but one useless record will be generated.

Any Solutions??

EDIT ------
My Web host does not provide a InnoDB engine.
Only MyISAM supported

Comment: You should look into transactions.

Comment: Note that the database engine must support transactions: MyISAM doesn't, InnoDB does

Comment: My web host doesn't provide a InnoDB Engine and that's the major reason for this problem....Any solutions for MyISAM

Comment: @user2439376 well, than you should make transaction table yourself, but this will be ugly

Comment: by transaction table i mean, that you insert record for each step, and before second query you verify that all previous steps are succeed

Comment: @user2439376 i will give an answer below

Comment: @kirugan i specified that the script has been terminated and the first query has been executed.

Comment: @user2439376 sry didn`t saw this, by the way why you use another table  for passwords?

Comment: @kirugan bad practice to store them together. Later i will store them in different database

Comment: @user2439376 bad practice? First time I heard such thing ... ok
Maybe you first query should be insert in password table with user_id and after that second query for specific user information?

Answer (score 3):

Use a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO foo ...
INSERT INTO bar ...
COMMIT
```

If either INSERT fails, you `ROLLBACK` the transaction and you won't be left with "useless" records.

Comment: Then you'll have to simulate a rollback. try to insert the first record. try to insert the second record. if either insert fails, delete the relevant row from the other table.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a transaction such as:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO TBL(...) VALUES(...);
INSERT INTO TBL(...) VALUES(...);
COMMIT;
```

Everything is sent to the mysql server in one go, and then ran as a batch, meaning your script can terminate as soon as the transfer is complete, rather than waiting for each individual query. It also has the added bonus of using less ram and being much faster.